# Get the model type for a passed in backbone.js model instance

Tags: javascript, model, backbone.js

How do I retrieve the model name for a backbone.js model instance?

For example:

```
var Topic = Backbone.Model.extend({

})
var topic = new Topic({ type: 'question' })

var doSomethingWithTopic = function(topic) {
  // check if passed in topic is of type Topic
  // something like topic.constructor.name === 'Topic'
}

doSomethingWithTopic(topic)
```

I realize I may be blurring the line between a backbone.js model and a class, so I am open to other ways of going about this if needed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the `instanceof` operator.

```
var doSomethingWithTopic = function(topic) {
  if( topic instanceof Topic ) {
    // do something with topic
  }
}
```

Comment: While this compares the model type with a known object, is it possible to get the model type of a Backbone object so that I can create a new instance of that model?

Comment: @NileshC: if `obj` is an existing object, then `var newObj = new (obj.constructor)();` will create a new instance of the same type.  This assumes that the object was "wired up" correctly when it was constructed (which is a safe assumption for objects created with Backbone).