# Get class type in CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript

How can I find that class of an object once it has been instantiated?

```
class Cat
  constructor: (@name) ->

class Dog
  constructor: (@name) ->

cat = new Cat "Kitty"
dog = new Dog "Doggy"

if (cat == Cat)  <- I want to do something like this
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just change the `==` to `instanceof`

```
if(cat instanceof Cat)
```

Comment: thanks for the specific code help.  It will help me with my project in figuring out the object type in an array.

Comment: is there a way though to get the name of the object with guessing and checking?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087712/get-the-model-type-for-a-passed-in-backbone-js-model-instance

Comment: Actually this question might be helpful as well. For some reason I never saw your comment @AlexisK http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript

Comment: From the response in the question above, the equivalent CoffeeScript could be: http://jsfiddle.net/SLtTs/

Answer (score 8):

If you wanted to know the type name of a particular object (which is what I was just looking for when I found this question), you can use the syntax `{object}.constructor.name`

for example

```
class Cat
    constructor: (@name) ->

  class Dog
    constructor: (@name) ->

  cat = new Cat()
  dog = new Dog()

  console.log cat.constructor.name
  console.log dog.constructor.name
```

which will output

```
Cat
Dog
```

Answer (score 5):

The way to do this is to check the type of an object using either

```
instanceof
```

or

```
typeof
```

i.e.

```
if (obj instanceof Awesomeness){
//doSomethingCrazy();
}
```

Just as in JavaScript, Coffee Script does not provide any abstraction over these functions

Comment: is there a way though to get the name of the object with guessing and checking?

Comment: @Alexis I think typeof is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIU, the general solution would be using `@constructor` - Useful when you don't know or don't want to specify the class name.

There was even [a discussion](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1639) regarding making @@ a shortcut for it.